# LDAP: "Unacceptable log file" after db recovery

Tags: ldap, openldap

My `openldap-2.4.21` server died I so checked the syslog messages and found logs reporting a corrupt db which I tried to fix by issuing:

```
$ /usr/bin/db4.8_recover -v -h /var/lib/ldap/
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 69 offset 120
Recovery starting from [68][84]
Recovery complete at Mon Nov  7 10:32:54 2011
Maximum transaction ID 80015fb4 Recovery checkpoint [70][28]
```

After that I tried to start `slapd` which failed because of an `Unacceptable log file`. That issue never happened to me before, `db4.*_recover` could always fix issues. What I know is that the ldap utils got upgraded from `db4.7` to `db4.8` recently.

```
$ /etc/init.d/slapd start

$ tail -f /var/log/syslog

Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4083]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.21 (Jun  2 2011 19:36:19) $#012#011buildd@allspice:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.21/debian/build/servers/slapd
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: hdb_db_open: database "dc=example,dc=org": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb(dc=example,dc=org): Unacceptable log file /var/lib/ldap/log.0000000067: unsupported log version 15
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb(dc=example,dc=org): Invalid log file: log.0000000067: Invalid argument
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb(dc=example,dc=org): PANIC: Invalid argument
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb(dc=example,dc=org): unable to join the environment
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: hdb_db_open: database "dc=example,dc=org" cannot be recovered, err -30974. Restore from backup!
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb(dc=example,dc=org): txn_checkpoint interface requires an environment configured for the transaction subsystem
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb_db_close: database "dc=example,dc=org": txn_checkpoint failed: Invalid argument (22).
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: backend_startup_one (type=hdb, suffix="dc=example,dc=org"): bi_db_open failed! (-30974)
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: bdb_db_close: database "dc=example,dc=org": alock_close failed
Nov  7 10:33:08 server slapd[4084]: slapd stopped.
```

If I look at the offending log file it seems properly created (same size and correct permissions)

```
$ ls -lh /var/lib/ldap

-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  10M 2011-11-07 08:50 log.0000000065
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  10M 2011-11-07 10:12 log.0000000066
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  10M 2011-11-07 10:17 log.0000000067
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  10M 2011-11-07 10:27 log.0000000068
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  10M 2011-11-07 10:27 log.0000000069
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap  30M 2011-10-28 10:30 mail.bdb
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap 2.5M 2011-10-28 10:30 objectClass.bdb
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap  18M 2011-10-28 10:30 sn.bdb
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap 2.2M 2011-10-28 10:30 uid.bdb
```

**Q1: How can I fix the unacceptable log file problem?**

I've tried to read the log files using `db4.8_printlog -h /var/lib/ldap` and so far it's been running for 1 hour displaying all the logged transactions. I'll update the question if it throws an error.

Also, when I run the db_recovery utility several times in a row WITHOUT restarting slapd in the meantime I see the last valid log file changing every time which I was not expecting

```
$ /usr/bin/db*.*_recover -v -h /var/lib/ldap/
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 71 offset 120
Recovery starting from [70][84]
Recovery complete at Mon Nov  7 10:41:15 2011
Maximum transaction ID 80015fb4 Recovery checkpoint [72][28]

$ /usr/bin/db*.*_recover -v -h /var/lib/ldap/
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 72 offset 120
Recovery starting from [71][84]
Recovery complete at Mon Nov  7 10:43:31 2011
Maximum transaction ID 80015fb4 Recovery checkpoint [73][28]
```

**Q2: Is that normal to see the last valid log file changing for every db recovery (without slapd being used at all)?**

Comment: Have you tried `file /var/lib/ldap/log.*` to see if your log files have conflicting DB versions? Over the years I've also seen similar problems with several different programs using BerkeleyDB, not only with OpenLDAP. BDB can be a bit painful sometimes.

Comment: Logs files prior to `log.0000000064` have version `14`. Subsequent logs have version `15`. This doesn't explain why it fails on `log.0000000067` and not `log.0000000064`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use the utilities which shipped in the OpenLDAP package:

```
$ rpm -ql openldap-servers | grep db_
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_archive
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_checkpoint
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_deadlock
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_dump
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_hotbackup
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_load
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_printlog
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_recover
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_stat
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_upgrade
/usr/sbin/slapd_db_verify
```

instead of from the `db4-utils` package:

```
/usr/bin/db_archive
/usr/bin/db_checkpoint
/usr/bin/db_deadlock
/usr/bin/db_dump
/usr/bin/db_dump185
/usr/bin/db_load
/usr/bin/db_printlog
/usr/bin/db_recover
/usr/bin/db_stat
/usr/bin/db_upgrade
/usr/bin/db_verify
```

Comment: Do you recommend a particular version for `openldap-servers`?

Comment: No. But notice that the version of BerkeleyDB which is built in OpenLDAP maybe different from the external package (often older than). It is why it has complained about the "unsupported log version 15".

Comment: Thanks. My point is, if the issue was strictly related to `unsupported log version 15`, why didn't `db_recover` fail on `log.0000000064` which is the first log to have `version 15` (i.e. why did it only fail 3 logs later on `log.0000000067`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough time for a little infrastructure overhaul, I'd heartily recommend the following:

- stop using the outdated distribution packages,
- start using packages from the [LDAP Toolbox](http://ltb-project.org/wiki/) project,
- switch the database format to MDB: the database is rock-stable, faster and uses half the memory the BDB-based databases used

(there's wealth of new features and bug fixes between 2.4.21 and 2.4.39, but stable MDB support is one of the most important features of the newer versions)